# Css can't change element by hovering over another

Tags: html, css

if i hover over the p-Element it animates only the text in the p but not the text of it's child elements. I've tried to fix it by trying #email:hover~p a but sadly it didnt work. Below you see an example, it has to target whe whole line; the whole text inside the element and of its children

```css
p{
  color: black;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: .5s;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
a:hover{
  color: transparent;
}
 #email:hover~p a{
  color: transparent;
  transition: .5s;
}
p:hover{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6666ff, #0099ff , #00ff00, #ff3399, #6666ff);
  color: transparent;
  background-size: 400% 100%;
  background-clip: text;
  animation: rainbow 35s linear infinite;
  transition: .5s;
}

@keyframes rainbow{
  to{
   background-position: 5500vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="email">Email: <a href="#">mail</a></p>
  <p>Username: User</p>
```

Comment: `#email:hover~p a{` this selector is wrong. try  `#email:hover a{`

Comment: Can you try to explain what exactly is you are trying to achieve. I can see the animations working, and the child elements can also be selected.

Comment: Add `p:hover a {color: transparent}`.

Comment: Thank you so much, i read on the internet that i have to use '~'. Do u know what '~' is used for in CSS?

Comment: @Igor, According to https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp, ~ would select all the `p` that is preceded by #email. So you don't need to use that, instead use `#email:hover a` or `p:hover a`, but since the latter is a more common way of selcting, it could cause issues, so better go with the former approach.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `#email:hover~p a` with `#email:hover a`

```css
p{
  color: black;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: .5s;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
a:hover{
  color: transparent;
}
 #email:hover a{
  color: transparent;
  transition: .5s;
}
p:hover{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6666ff, #0099ff , #00ff00, #ff3399, #6666ff);
  color: transparent;
  background-size: 400% 100%;
  background-clip: text;
  animation: rainbow 35s linear infinite;
  transition: .5s;
}

@keyframes rainbow{
  to{
   background-position: 5500vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="email">Email: <a href="#">mail</a></p>
  <p>Username: User</p>
```